# How to sum order cost

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, join, sum

I have a problem to show the total sales amount (in other words, sum the Price) for customers total orders. With the following SQL statement, I manage to join the tables 'Order1', 'Order2' and 'Customers' to reach the necessary attributes to show the correct city for customers who have made at least 3 orders and to sum the order quantity to this:

```
SELECT c.CityName, SUM(o2.Orderquantity) AS 'Total sales amount'
FROM Order1 o1 
INNER JOIN
(SELECT o1.CustomerNr 
FROM Order1 o1 
GROUP BY o1.CustomerNr
HAVING COUNT(o1.CustomerNr) >= 3)
AS a ON o1.CustomerNr = a.CustomerNr 
INNER JOIN Order2 o2 ON o1.Ordernr = o2.Ordernr 
INNER JOIN Customers c ON o1.CustomerNr = c.CustomerNr
GROUP BY c.CityName
```

The structures of the tables I work with look like:

- 'Customers' has the columns: CustomerNr, City Name
- 'Order1' has columns: Ordernr, CustomerNr
- 'Order2' has columns: Ordernr, Productnr, Order quantity
- 'Products' has columns: ProductNr, Price

So, what I want is to be able to show the city of customers who have made at least 3 orders (so far so good), but also with the the total sales amount (instead of the total order quantity) for these customers, does anyone know how I can do that according to the table structures above?

Sample data:
Sample data for the table 'Customers':

```
 - CustomerNr  CityName:
 - 01109       New York
 - 01999       Los Angeles
 - 08120       London

Sample data for 'Order1':

 - Ordernr  CustomerNr
 - 1306     1109
 - 1306     1109
 - 1307     1109

Sample data for 'Order2':

 - OrderNr   ProductNr  Order   quantity:
 - 1306      15-116     01109   3
 - 1306      46-701     01109   2
 - 1307      15-96      01109   1
 - 1308      17-91      18208   1

(etc...)

Sample data for 'Products':

 - ProductNr  Price:
 - 15-116     44.00
 - 15-96      28.50
 - 46-701     3000.00

etc...
```

As you can see in 'Order1' a customer can be linked to serveral ordernr, and as you can see in 'Products', every product has its unique productnr with its price. And as you can see in 'Order2', the customer 1109 has (in this case) bought 7 15-115-products and 1 46-708-products for order 1306. But this customer has also bought 2 of 15-96-products in another order (1307). This customer, which is from New York, has done 2 orders in total, so in that case the result should look like this:

CityName, Total sales amount:
New York, 6160.50

Comment: Renaming to the same table alias (o1) in several places is very confusing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have to **JOIN** of **Products** table in your query

Try this:

```
SELECT c.CityName, SUM(o2.quantity * p.Price) AS 'TotalSalesAmount'
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT Ordernr, CustomerNr FROM Order1) AS o1 
INNER JOIN (SELECT o1.CustomerNr 
            FROM Order1 o1 
            GROUP BY o1.CustomerNr 
            HAVING COUNT(o1.CustomerNr) >= 3
           ) AS a ON o1.CustomerNr = a.CustomerNr 
INNER JOIN Order2 o2 ON o1.Ordernr = o2.Ordernr 
INNER JOIN Customers c ON o1.CustomerNr = c.CustomerNr
INNER JOIN Products P ON o2.ProductNr = P.ProductNr
GROUP BY c.CityName;
```

Comment: With this SQL statement I notice that it only sums the price for unique product numbers once in orders, but with the values I have in my tables, a customer can buy, let say, 5 products (of one unique productnr) and 2 products (of another unique productnr). So what I want is to be able to sum the total sales amount for the total quantity for a customer linked to total orders they've made. Do you know how to solve that?

Comment: Sample data for the table Customer:
CustomerNr, CityName:
01109, New York
01999, Los Angeles
08120, London
Etc..

Sample data for Order1:
OrderNr, CustomerNr:
1306, 01999
1307, 01109
1308, 08120

Sample data for Products:
ProductNr, Price:
15-116, 44.00
15-96, 28.50
etc...

Comment: Now I've updated my first post with some sample data with the desired result.

Comment: @ecinna Check my updated answer... Also Want to know that what is the unique key between Order1 And Order2 table.